# What's the name of this type of connector

Tags: connector

What's the name of the connector in the picture below? Is it suitable to use such connector and wires as signal wires routed from main PCB to the front panel for ethernet and USB?

---

Update:

After some more searching on Google, I finally find the name and one vendor who make this type of connector, http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf. It's name is "2.5mm pitch/Disconnectable Crimp style connectors".

But I still want to get some information about using this type of connector with the standard USB/Ethernet cable to connect the main PCB and the standard USB/Ethernet connector mounted on front panel. Or there are other better choices?

[image]

Comment: It would be a bad idea to use these to extend USB and/or Ethernet. Controlled impedance is expected on those lines (the differential data lines on the USB, for example). It may sort-of work at lower speeds but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany: Then what about just using that connector, and using a standard USB/Ethernet cable instead? Or I need a more compact IDC connector such as this http://www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board/2mm/terminals.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 2.5mm pitch 10 pin "JST XH" connector.

[Manufacturers Page](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277)

#### EDIT:

I see you already found it, never mind. Didn't look on the date of the question, it just appeared in the recent list of questions.

---

[image]

(picture is from an [Aliexpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/JST-XH-2-54mm-8-Pin-Female-Connector-with-Wire-and-male-connector-x-10-sets/1628402649.html) store, I claim no rights to it, nor am I advertising them, just useful as a reference image. )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without knowing the exact pitch, but it looks a lot like a [molex picoblade series](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction).

With no proof to support this statement, i would say it would probably work for short runs for ethernet and usb, but it is not the ideal way of doing it as the wires are not shielded nor length matched which will degrade signal integrity at frequency at which ethernet and usb work - especially for full speed usb and gigabit ethernet.

Comment: This is definitely not Molex PicoBlade series.  PicoBlade has flat pins.  I agree that it's difficult to identify this connector without knowing the pitch.  There are also no scale references on the board.

Comment: The pitch is 2.54mm.

Comment: Agreed, with that pitch it is definitely not a picoblade.